# Help choosing component values for a relay delay circuit

Tags: relay, schematics, timer, component-selection

I want to build a circuit that controls a relay with the following specifications:

1. the relay should turn on and stay on for ~60 seconds after the button is pushed
2. the relay should stay on as long as there is a PWM signal on the input and also for 2 seconds after the PWM dies out (assume 50% PWM, can adjust if necessary)

Here is a circuit I came up with:

[image: circuit]

I would like to know if it will work in theory, and also how to choose values for the resistors and capacitors (the other components I would prefer to keep at the following, 2n3906 transistors, 1n4004 diodes, and a 5v g5le relay (80mA coil current)

The time values do not need to be super precise, but I would prefer something around +-10% tolerance

Is this something that would be easier to make on a breadboard and swap values until it meets the criteria? if so, should I start out with the PWM time delay and then focus on the button?

Comment: Why don't you try simulating it in LTSpice (free of course).

Comment: @Andyaka looking into it doesn't seem like a bad idea, but I haven't used it before and some of the components don't seem to be easy to add into it (the button and the pwm inputs in particular - the relay also, but that I can re-create from more basic components)

Comment: LTSpice has buttons (switches) that can be activated with a repeating timing signal and relays model like resistors. PWM input is a signal that can be generated from a voltage source. yes it's a steep learning curve but worth it.

Comment: Your circuit won't work as it's drawn, but it looks like what you're trying to do is turn the relay ON when the switch is made OR when there's a PWM input. Am I right?

Comment: @EMFields yes, but I also want the switch to have a time-delay on it's release - might I ask what the specific problem with it is?

Comment: Basically, the transistors will never turn on except for a few moments during power-up for Q1,  and the catch diode should be across the relay coil, not the supply.  I've worked out a fix, but i can't post it right now; I'm off to the doctor's...

Answer (score 1):

Your circuit has a few problems, the first being that since Q1 is PNP, making S1 won't turn it ON, it'll just charge up C1 which will keep Q1 OFF, forever, since C1 has no discharge path.

The same problem exists for Q2 in that a positive rectified and smoothed PWM signal never turn it ON either.

Then there's  the catch diode, which should be across the relay coil, not the supply.

The following LTspice schematic and plot is basically your circuit, fixed and functional.  However, the 60 second delay would require a BFC and the relay doesn't snap OFF, like it should for either the 60 second or the 2 second PWM release delay, which will cause problems.

The yellow trace is the manual trigger, the red trace is the PWM trigger, the blue trace is the voltage across the relay coil, and the relay OFF delays are short because I just wanted to show the circuit working.

[image]

The following schematic and plot show a much better circuit since it uses smallish caps for timing, a comparator to do the delay switching, and a snappy relay driver.

The yellow trace is the manual trigger, the red trace is the PWM trigger, and the green trace is the current through the relay coil.

Also, the LTspice circuit list follows just in case you want to play with the circuit, which works like this:

**THE RELAY DRIVER**

K1, the relay, is low-side driven by Q1, and D4 is used to clamp the spike generated by the coil's inductance - when Q1 switches OFF abruptly - to Vcc plus 1 diode drop.

Q1's drive is supplied by R7, which is held quiescently low by U1, a voltage comparator, who's output goes high when its non-inverting (+) input is more positive than its inverting (-) input.

**THE REFERENCE**

R5 and R6 comprise a voltage divider used to generate a reference voltage of about 1.4 volts at U1-, and with no signal on U1+, U1- will be more positive than U1+, U1's output will be low, and the relay will be OFF.

**THE PWM TRIGGER**

If there's a PWM signal being generated by V3, when that signal goes positive it'll charge C2 quickly through D2 and R3, but when it goes to zero volts (ground) D2 will be reverse biased and C2 will discharge slowly, to ground, through R4, the discharge path through R2 being blocked by D1.

The voltage on C2 is connected to U1+ through D3, and when U1+ goes more positive than U1-, U1's output will go high, turning Q1 ON, which will then turn the relay ON.

When the PWM signal stops, C2 will discharge to ground through R4, and when the voltage on U1+ becomes less positive than the reference voltage on U1-, U1's output will go low, turning Q1 and the relay OFF.

Thus, the time it takes for the voltage on U1+ to decay to less than the voltage on U1- is the time the relay will be energized. Note that D1 is used to isolate the PWM trigger circuitry from the manual trigger circuitry and prevents C2 from discharging through R2.

**THE MANUAL TRIGGER**

When S1 is made, C1 charges to Vcc quickly through S1 and R1, and as soon as the voltage on U1+ goes more positive than the voltage on U1-, U1's output will go high, turning Q1 and the relay ON for as long as S1 is made.

When S1 opens, C1 discharges slowly through R2, (the discharge path through R4 being blocked by D3) and when the voltage on U1+ becomes less positive than the reference voltage on U1-, U1's output will go low, turning Q1 and the relay OFF.

Thus, the time it takes for the voltage on U1+ to decay to less than the voltage on U1- is the time the relay will be energized.

[image]

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 1288 752
WIRE 592 -352 -448 -352
WIRE 704 -352 592 -352
WIRE 816 -352 704 -352
WIRE 976 -352 816 -352
WIRE 1056 -352 976 -352
WIRE 1056 -320 1056 -352
WIRE 592 -256 592 -352
WIRE 816 -256 816 -352
WIRE 976 -256 976 -352
WIRE 1056 -208 1056 -240
WIRE 976 -64 976 -192
WIRE 1056 -64 1056 -128
WIRE 1056 -64 976 -64
WIRE 704 -48 704 -352
WIRE 592 -32 592 -176
WIRE 672 -32 592 -32
WIRE 816 -16 816 -176
WIRE 816 -16 736 -16
WIRE 912 -16 816 -16
WIRE -448 0 -448 -352
WIRE -336 0 -448 0
WIRE -224 0 -256 0
WIRE -112 0 -144 0
WIRE -16 0 -112 0
WIRE 48 0 -16 0
WIRE 464 0 112 0
WIRE 672 0 464 0
WIRE 464 48 464 0
WIRE -112 160 -112 0
WIRE -16 160 -16 0
WIRE 176 176 144 176
WIRE 272 176 240 176
WIRE 384 176 352 176
WIRE 464 176 464 112
WIRE 464 176 384 176
WIRE 464 240 464 176
WIRE 592 240 592 -32
WIRE 384 256 384 176
WIRE -448 272 -448 0
WIRE -320 272 -320 48
WIRE 144 272 144 176
WIRE -448 400 -448 352
WIRE -320 400 -320 352
WIRE -320 400 -448 400
WIRE -272 400 -272 48
WIRE -272 400 -320 400
WIRE -112 400 -112 224
WIRE -112 400 -272 400
WIRE -16 400 -16 240
WIRE -16 400 -112 400
WIRE 144 400 144 352
WIRE 144 400 -16 400
WIRE 384 400 384 320
WIRE 384 400 144 400
WIRE 464 400 464 320
WIRE 464 400 384 400
WIRE 592 400 592 320
WIRE 592 400 464 400
WIRE 704 400 704 16
WIRE 704 400 592 400
WIRE 976 400 976 32
WIRE 976 400 704 400
WIRE -448 496 -448 400
FLAG -448 496 0
SYMBOL cap -128 160 R0
SYMATTR InstName C1
SYMATTR Value 10µ
SYMBOL diode 992 -192 R180
WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName D4
SYMATTR Value 1N4148
SYMBOL voltage -448 256 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 0 23 13 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value 5
SYMBOL ind 1040 -224 R0
SYMATTR InstName L1
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL res 1040 -336 R0
SYMATTR InstName R8
SYMATTR Value 63
SYMBOL sw -240 0 M270
SYMATTR InstName S1
SYMBOL voltage -320 256 R0
WINDOW 0 -59 11 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 96 Invisible 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMATTR Value PULSE(0 5 1 10m 10m 1)
SYMBOL npn 912 -64 R0
SYMATTR InstName Q1
SYMATTR Value 2N2222
SYMBOL res -32 144 R0
SYMATTR InstName R2
SYMATTR Value 4.7meg
SYMBOL res 576 -272 R0
WINDOW 0 -55 36 Left 2
WINDOW 3 -67 68 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName R5
SYMATTR Value 100k
SYMBOL res 576 224 R0
SYMATTR InstName R6
SYMATTR Value 39k
SYMBOL res 800 -272 R0
WINDOW 0 -46 40 Left 2
WINDOW 3 -63 72 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName R7
SYMATTR Value 1000
SYMBOL res -128 -16 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 1000
SYMBOL diode 48 16 R270
WINDOW 0 32 32 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName D1
SYMATTR Value 1N4148
SYMBOL voltage 144 256 R0
WINDOW 0 19 7 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 96 Invisible 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V3
SYMATTR Value PULSE(0 5 70 100n 100n 500u 1000u 1000)
SYMBOL diode 176 192 R270
WINDOW 0 32 32 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 0 32 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName D2
SYMATTR Value 1N4148
SYMBOL res 368 160 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName R3
SYMATTR Value 1000
SYMBOL cap 368 256 R0
SYMATTR InstName C2
SYMATTR Value 1µ
SYMBOL res 448 224 R0
SYMATTR InstName R4
SYMATTR Value 2meg
SYMBOL diode 480 112 R180
WINDOW 0 24 64 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName D3
SYMATTR Value 1N4148
SYMBOL Comparators\\LT1716 704 -16 R0
SYMATTR InstName U1
TEXT -440 432 Left 2 !.model SW SW(Ron=.01 Roff=1G Vt=2.5 Vh=0)
TEXT -440 464 Left 2 !.tran 100 startup uic
TEXT 696 432 Left 2 ;EM  FIELDS  21 APR 2016
```

Comment: Thanks for the analysis, I will play with it a bit - Would V2 essentially be gone because it's a LTSpice thing, and V1 be replaced by the PWM? is there anything to ensure that if I get a 100% PWM signal (or a high, with no drops), it cuts the relay?

Comment: @user2813274:  V2 would go away, but V1 would stay since it's the 5 volt supply, not the PWM source. V3 is the PWM source, and if you want the relay to drop out if/when the PWM stays high, connect a capacitor in series with the PWM source and D2 anode, and connect a 1N4148 with its cathode connected to the junction of the new capacitor and D2, and its anode to ground.